# Firebase messaging background handler not called when app is terminated (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to update my app's badge count number of my flutter app when receiving push notifications when the app is terminated.

The Firebase messaging background handler works fine if the app is in the background but doesn't work when the app is terminated.

I have read in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#receiving-messages) :

> On iOS, if the user swipes away the application from app Switcher, it must be manually reopened again for background messages to start working again.

Does it mean that on iOS there is no way to update the badge count using the firebase background handler (by the logic you implement in the handler of course, just need the handler to be called) ?

Any app do this today so i wonder why it would not be possible with Firebase Messaging.

Comment: In my case I wanted to save notification data in background but sharedprefrence wasn't working in packground, and solution was 
```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        SharedPreferencesAndroid.registerWith();
        PathProviderAndroid.registerWith();
      }
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        SharedPreferencesIOS.registerWith();
        PathProviderIOS.registerWith();
      }
```
I think in your case you need to register your app badge package something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MerdanDev, indeed you are right the `SharedPreferences` package had an issue when used in Background isolates because it was not linked to the same preferences path that we are using in our app. 
This should have been fixed in flutter 3.0.0+ but i had not time to try it out yet, but my question is more about the "terminated" state of the app.

Comment: Yes in terminated case it should work as background, both of them handled by background handler. Otherwise I don't know, maybe app badge packege has some problem. I wanted to do similar thing like you, but in my case instead of firebase notification I would like to use something like firebase in app messaging for background, my goal is background service without count badge count without notification. If you you have any idea thanx for that!

Comment: See my answer i have found a solution for my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found a solution, by using a service extension in swift and passing data as payload server side, using `content-available: true` in python.

Here is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.cn/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.messaging?hl=zh-tw#aps) i have followed to implement the notification server side.

Also, there is an [ongoing](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9300) bug / feature request for flutter and Firebase regarding this case.

Answer (score 0):

##### I find the solution for my case. I use Node.js to send notifications.

##### From [official Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app).

You should use

```json
{
   "aps" : {
      "content-available" : 1
   },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting 'content-available': 1 from the node JS Admin in my case did the trick. Code sample here.

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app#2980040

```
const message = {
             apns: {
                  payload: {
                     aps: {
                         'content-available': 1
                     }
                  }
             },
             data: {foo:'foo'},
             notification:{
                title: title,
                body: text
             },
             token: pushToken,
                                
          };
```